# Backup live server, migrate to new hard drive (simulating recovery from hard drive failure)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, bios, initramfs

Goal: to take image of live system, transfer to new drive (from MBR, to GPT), separate /boot from / partition, and not have to go through tedious system re-install and re-configure from fresh.

Current setup:
Ubuntu 14.04 server running on an old system (Athlon 64) - on MBR 160GB `/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 - 77G - /
/dev/sda2 - Linux Swap`

GPT 3.0TB disk on /dev/sdc:
`/dev/sdc1 - 2MB - grub_bios
/dev/sdc2 - 700MB - /boot
/dev/sdc3 - 344GB - /
/dev/sdc4 - 2.0TB - /some_other_data`

Did:
`#: mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/tmp; mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/tmp2`
`#: cd /; sudo tar cf - --one-file-system --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups / |  ( cd /mnt/tmp; sudo tar xvf - )`

Then:
`#: mv /mnt/tmp/boot /mnt/tmp2/`

Modified /mnt/tmp/etc/fstab:
    `# <file system> <mount point>    <type>  <options> <dump>  <pass>`
    `#Old root -- UUID=4ed11d31-61ad-435e-908e-3443e802291a  /  ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=a1870c6a-a3b1-4d04-b65f-ee4e41b9c5b8 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=c53ef2f7-9688-4aea-9311-23c44a9ae82c /boot ext2 errors=remount-ro 0 1`

Then I mounted the proc and sys filesystems under /mnt/tmp and -o bind /dev, /dev/pts and /run there as well. Then I chrooted to /mnt/tmp, and mounted /dev/sdc2 to (the new) /boot.

Next I:
`#: grub-install /dev/sdc; update-grub; update-initramfs -u; reboot`

At boot, I select the large GPT disk to boot from, [grub2 menu comes up, shows the correct install options, etc. -- UUID a1870c6a-a3b1-4d04-b65f-ee4e41b9c5b8 is set to root, part_gpt insmod'ed, ext2 insmod'ed, etc..](http://pastebin.com/XYedgaBk)

I continue, kernel begins to load, I see, among other things, /dev/sda is polled, some usb devices are recognized, and then it pauses... and after a brief delay I am told that it cannot find /dev/disk/by-uuid/a1870c6a-a3b1-4d04-b65f-ee4e41b9c5b8 and I am dropped to a busybox shell.

My usb keyboard does not work at this prompt, and I am stuck.

I feel like I am missing something very basic, and I would appreciate whatever help this community can provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't get very much input into my problem, but I uncovered a solution and will post it here for posterity. The clue came from [this article](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_kernel_problems#Can.27t_find_root_filesystem_.2F_error_mounting_.2Fdev.2Froot)

I needed to add two modules to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
1) `sata_nv` which is what makes the SATA controller where the GPT drive connects, work
2) `usbhid` just in case I get dumped into a busybox shell again.

Then simply:
`#: update-initramfs -c -k <kernel version>; reboot; profit`